# Java run command in ALREADY RUNNING CMD window

Tags: java, windows, cmd, command-prompt

I am creating a little program to take away some of my work by using a GUI.
What I have right now is a little program with a button "Start" which starts a CMD-based application. What I need to do is enter a certain command in that CMD window. I want to add a button which fills out this command for me.

Is this even possible?

P.S.: CMD is Windows's Command Prompt.

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't believe you can control a CMD window from a Java application. However you can create a window which looks like a CMD window which works any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if it is an external command:

```
String command = "cmd";   //Replace with your command
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

If it is an internal command then that will not work, but there is a workaround: create a batch file with the commands in it, and put a String with the path to the batch file as an argument.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Temp.bat");
```

Or you can write the batch file programmatically using this method:

```
private void batch(String commands){
  try{
    String filename = "Temp.bat";
    File f = new File(filename);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f);
    writer.print(commands);
    writer.close();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filename);

    long x = getTime + 3000;
    do{
      //Wait
    }while(getTime < x);

    f.delete();
  }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private long getTime(){
  SimpleDateFormat datef = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS");
  Date date = new Date();
  return Long.parseLong("" + datef.format(date));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your CMD-based application receives its input.

If it receives input from the input stream of the CMD window, this article explains how to get a reference to the input stream and send messages to it: [Java exec - execute system processes with Java ProcessBuilder and Process](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1).

If your CMD window is running a command that doesn't take input, and you want to execute another command, then I think you would have to run your second command in a separate CMD process.

Comment: The CMD get its input from a C++ application. The application is closed-source so I cannot change anything in there.

Comment: Does the C++ application read its input from the CMD command line? If so, then the Java Process Builder method should work just the same.

Comment: The C++ (DLL file) opens a CMD window to give the output. So the DLL sends its output to the CMD window. I want to grab the content of that window.

It would be easy if I could modify the DLL by saving the contents to a text file every X seconds and let Java read that text file. Hmmm

Comment: You can redirect the output from a program like this: